# In the lightning page, how to get click events and data in the iframe

Tags: lightning, iframe

How do I get the iframe data in the lightning page?

For example, the user enters a customer name in the iframe, and the outer lighting page needs to display the customer's detailed information page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Window.postMessage(message, vfOrigin)` for sending data from iframe page to lightning component.

Complete example is available at [salesforce blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html).

Answer (score 0):

After my efforts, I finally realized this function.
[image]

[image]

[image]